# ORDERing by with subquery / join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I wanted to display top users ordered by the most number of posts. The users posts and users are both in a different table, so I had to COUNT the postid with the userid of the user.

How do I make a query so I could display and order the users?

I've been browsing the web for hours and read about Subqueryies like JOIN. But idk if I am doing it right, doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
 // Counts all the posts of the user
$query = "SELECT COUNT(postid) as `totalposts` FROM users_posts WHERE userid = '$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//Select all users
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 5";
$result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
```

Comment: @Dharman Thank you so much for this information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
        from users_posts up
        where up.userid = u.userid
       ) as total_posts
from users u
order by total_posts desc;
```